# Is it possible to detect unique colours inside an SVG?

Tags: svg, vector, imagemagick, inkscape

I want to access all the colours that an SVG may be using. I've played with `convert`, but would like some direction on how to figure out the unique colours that an SVG may contain.

This is the PHP code I've written to talk to `convert`, to try and determine whether a bitmap contains colours, however it is very limited:

```
/**
 * containsColor
 * 
 * @see     https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19580&start=15
 * @see     https://superuser.com/questions/508472/how-to-recognize-black-and-white-images
 * @see     https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19580
 * @access  public
 * @static
 * @param   string $path
 * @return  bool
 */
public static function containsColor(string $path): bool
{
    $commands = array(
        'convert ' .
            ($path) .' ' .
            '-format "%[colorspace]" info:'
    );
    $command = implode(' && ', $commands);
    $response = exec($command);
    $color = strtolower($response) !== 'gray';
    return $color;
}
```

Comment: What if there's a gradient? Is that an infinite number of colours between the stops. What about an feColorMatrix filter?

Comment: @RobertLongson Ideally, if a gradient is defined (eg. https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app.local.getstencil.com/upld1e2rwbzz.svg), it would be marked as "coloured".

Answer (score 2):

If we review [Format and Print Image Properties](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) document, we should be able to identify the unique color count with `-format %k`.

```php
public static function containsColor(string $path): int
{
    $commands = array(
        'convert ' .
            ($path) .' ' .
            '-format "%k" info:'
    );
    $command = implode(' && ', $commands);
    $response = exec($command);
    return (int)$response;
}
```

If you want to evaluate all colors used by the SVG post render, you can use [`-unique-colors`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#unique-colors) operator.

```
convert input.svg -depth 8 -unique-colors txt:-
```

Which will output something that can easily be parsed by PHP.

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 403,1,65535,srgba
0,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000FF  black
1,0: (257,0,0,65535)  #010000FF  srgba(1,0,0,1)
2,0: (257,257,257,65535)  #010101FF  srgba(1,1,1,1)
3,0: (257,257,0,65535)  #010100FF  srgba(1,1,0,1)
4,0: (514,257,0,65535)  #020100FF  srgba(2,1,0,1)
5,0: (771,771,771,65535)  #030303FF  grey1
...
```

Remember that SVG is really just XML, so it may be possible to load it into a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class, and use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to extract color attributes. But as correctly mentioned in the comments, you would not be able to identify CSS3 filters, or advanced color rendering & mixing.

**Update with working example**

```php
public static function containsColor(string $input) : bool
{
    $pixelInfoList = [];
    exec(sprintf('convert "%s" -depth 8 -alpha Off --colors 255 -unique-colors txt:-', $input), $pixelInfoList);
    // ... Insert error handling here ...
    for($index = 1; $index < count($pixelInfoList); $index++) {
        preg_match('/\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)/', $pixelInfoList[$index], $colorParts);
        if ($colorParts[1] == $colorParts[2] && $colorParts[2] == $colorParts[3]) {
            // Color is gray. Do nothing?
        } else {
            // Non-gray color. Stop search, and return.
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Not perfect, but a start.

This works be evaluating the color channels outputted by `txt:-`. If the red, green, and blue channels are the same, we can state it's a gray color & continue to the next line, else we can state a non-gray color exists & stop the iterations. I'm also taking the library of using `-alpha Off -colors 255` to through out additional data.

YMMV

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @emcconville
I'm at a bit of a loss on how to interpret the response. For simple black/grey vectors, I'm getting a limited response like: https://i.imgur.com/NYCfHQ2.png  But for more colourful ones, I'm getting 700+ lines of response

Comment: And then this one, which has no fill or stroke defined, is also responding back with  number of lines: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app.local.getstencil.com/upld5qsk1qa0.svg

Comment: Correct. The same vector graphic rendered in different sizes will drastically alter the amount of unique colors. Mostly due to antialiasing and color blending by the renderer. I'll update my answer with a example that _may_ work, but you would be responsible to build a solution that works for your localized business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to consider filters and mixing of colors, then the following code works quite well.

It might not find black because it is often not declared, since it is the standard color if none is specified.

This is just for finding the colors that are declared in the SVG code itself, and does not take CSS into account. It would be pretty easy though to do the same for CSS. It only looks for hex codes, but it could easily be extended to search for other color options.

```
$colors=array();
if(preg_match_all("/(?:color|fill|stroke)\s*[=]\s*[\"]?[#]([a-z0-9]+)/i",$html,$matches)){
    $colors=$matches[1];
    $colors=array_unique($colors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't help you, because you seem to want to use this for a server application, but it might help others with the same question.

If you're using Inkscape, you can also just export as .gpl.
File > Save a Copy : GIMP Palette (*.gpl)

This will, however, not save all the colors that are displayed within a gradient, only those that are actually used in the file.

Comment: can you go more into detail on what this accomplishes? I ask because Inkscape has a command line (CLI) version, so if this accomplishes exactly what I'm looking for, I may be able to look into the CLI equivalent of it.

Comment: It's not possible to call the output extension that exports a gimp palette file from the command line, currently. That's why I wrote that it won't help you. If you can write a bit of Python, you could probably convert it into a normal extension, and use it from cli (but would require a GUI). It goes through the document and collects all color values it finds, then saves as .gpl file. Code: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/extensions/blob/master/export_gimp_palette.py

Comment: Interesting; okay I have a lot of research to do :) Thanks for your help. Will follow up once I've given this a go.